# Is there something like an XPath to all the properties of a document in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize, document-configuration, sectsty

I'm trying to use LaTeX to format a document (I'm a casual user of LaTeX, in that I don't make my own document classes—but I can tweak them).

I have set up a document using the standard LaTeX commands such as `section`, `subsection`, etc.

What I want to do now is experimentally tweak a long list of document attributes, untill I get my document to look like I want.

Based on my current research, if I want to tweak section headings I have to use the package `sectsty`.

Is there nothing that lets me list out the properties I want to play with using a path mechanism, like:

```
\propertySet{\section\heading, Georgia\14pt}
\propertySet{\subsection\heading, Georgia\12pt}
\propertySet{\vspacingBeforeTitle, 0pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

Comment: Package [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) has way more customizable options than `sectsty`.  If you're using the KOMA classes, they have all of this built in.

Comment: If you need formatting help, the question must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You might prefer ConTeXt. That seems closer to what you want in that it is all-in-one. Memoir might be of interest - it is not as extensive as KOMA, but the documentation is very good and it is much simpler. You don't have to use `sectsty` to change section headings. You don't have to use a package at all.

Comment: But in LaTeX itself the answer is 'no'. There is no such mechanism. Period. And there is no class or package which provides any such mechanism as that you describe. In the future, there may be. But right now, nothing doing. If there was, it would probably be key-value rather than the syntax you show. (I use this extensively for document configuration with custom classes and packages.) Right now, ConTeXt is probably your best bet.